# How to find a row and extract data from row in csv file (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

The title is kind of bad, so let me use an example.

```
name,gender,age
mark,male,20
christine,female,24
bob,male,14
```

Using the above example, I want to find Bob's age. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the csv using pandas and then find the age of bob:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("<file_path>")
bobs_age = df[df['name'] == 'bob']['age']
print(bobs_age)
```

Another way is to read the csv line by line:

```
import csv
with open("<file_path>", newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in csv_reader:
        name, gender, age = row
        if name == 'bob':
            bobs_age = age
print(bobs_age)
```

Comment: For me it returns this

2    14
Name: age, dtype: int64

I don't know why it does that. For some reason it can be used for math (If I do bobs_age += 4 it returns the same weird thing but the 14 is an 18), but is there a way to get the number only? I'll mark this as an answer since it solved my problem, but I'd appreciate it if you could answer this too.

Comment: just add this to bobs_age: `bobs_age.values[0]`